# Removing a specific entry from an XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml file

```
- <annotations>
  - <annotation value="Black and white, outdoor" eventID="1">
          <image location="0928262.JPG" /> 
    </annotation>

  - <annotation value="CLear, obstacles" eventID="2">
          <image location="0928262.JPG" /> 
    </annotation>
  </annotations>
```

I have a function that takes in the file location and then deletes that from the xml file, like so,

```
private void remEntry(String fName)
{
    string xmlFile = path + "\\output.xml";

    if (File.Exists(xmlFile))
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);

        foreach (var x in xdoc.Descendants("annotation").ToList())
        {
            foreach (var el in xdoc.Descendants("image").ToList())
            {
                if (el.Attribute("location").Value == fName)
                {
                    el.Remove();

                }
            }
        }
        xdoc.Save(xmlFile);
    }
}
```

And this works, but I have a problem, this code will remove **all** the instance of the file name from the xml file, I only want to remove filename tied to a specific eventID. The event ID is displayed on the application in a text window. So, I added the following to the loop

```
foreach (var x in xdoc.Descendants("annotation").ToList())
{
    foreach (var el in xdoc.Descendants("image").ToList())
    {
        if (el.Attribute("location").Value == fName &&        
            x.Attribute("eventID").Value == eventID.Text)
        {
            el.Remove();

        }
    }
```

The idea here is, if the image name is equal to the input and if the eventID of the image is same as the EventID displayed then remove the element. But it still removes all instance of the file name.

Here is the expected result, where the eventID = 2.

```
- <annotations>
      - <annotation value="Black and white, outdoor
              <image location="0928262.JPG" /> 
        </annotation>

      - <annotation value="CLear, obstacles" eventID="2">

        </annotation>
      </annotations>
```

Here is what I'm getting,

```
- <annotations>
      - <annotation value="Black and white, outdoor" eventID="1">

        </annotation>

      - <annotation value="CLear, obstacles" eventID="2">

        </annotation>
      </annotations>
```

Comment: In your expected result, the Xml doesn't seem to be quite well-formed. In any case, can you execute your code with stepwise debugging and check the values of `x` and `el` when the `el.Remove();` line is executed? That may bring you on the right track. (+1 for the clearly structured, (as far as the question is concerned) complete and comprehensible question.)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: You should remove `ToList` from your `XDocument.Descendants` calls. `Descendants` returns an `IEnumerable` which enables the use of your `foreach` loops; there's no need to convert it to a `List`, which uses unnecessary cycles and creates garbage.
I will also second ORMapper that the code has no apparent errors. You need to run the debugger and find out what's wrong.

Comment: @Kivin: When `el.Remove()` is called, the collection is changed, which may cause problems with the enumerable. Therefore, `ToList()` has its reasons in this case.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I did that before, both `x` and `el` had the values I was expecting, but the issue was caused due to me removing it from the whole document as opposed to Descendants of the current element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your method to the following and it will work

```
foreach (var x in xdoc.Descendants("annotation").ToList())
{
  foreach (var el in x.Descendants("image").ToList())
  {
    if (el.Attribute("location").Value == loc && x.Attribute("eventID").Value == id)
    {
      el.Remove();
    }
  }
}
```

The second foreach needs to get the Descendants of the current element that is provided by the first foreach.

Your code gets the Descendants always from the complete document, what results in that when the first foreach encounters the element with `eventID == 2` it will remove all images with the specified location from the complete document.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using embedded *foreach* loops to find a node to be removed you can also use XPath query. To do so, firstly you have to import *System.Xml.XPath* namespace:

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
```

Then use the following code:

```
var id = 1;
var fileName = "0928262.JPG";
foreach (var x in xdoc.XPathSelectElements(String.Format(@"//annotation[@eventID={0}]/image[@location=""{1}""]", id, fileName)))
{
    x.Remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in inner foreach loop you are having xdoc.descendents(), which is giving you both image elements. Try to use x.Descendents()-

`foreach (var el in x.Descendants("image").ToList())`

Answer (score 1):

.It seems that the nesting of your loops is incorrect. Initially you loop over all annotations in the document:
`foreach (var x in xdoc.Descendants("annotation").ToList())` and the you loop over all images in the document: `foreach (var el in xdoc.Descendants("image").ToList())`

If you would print the location and eventID's you would get this:

- eventID 1, 0928262.JPG (first location)
- eventID 1, 0928262.JPG (second location)
- eventID 2, 0928262.JPG (first location)
- eventID 2, 0928262.JPG (second location)

As you can see from this output you will match your criteria for removing the entry twice.

What you probably should do is something like:

```
foreach (var x in xdoc.Descendants("annotation").ToList())
{
    foreach (var el in x.Descendants("image").ToList())
    {
        if (el.Attribute("location").Value == fName &&
            x.Attribute("eventID").Value == eventID.Text)
        {
            el.Remove();
        }
    }
}
```